# How to update xml by filtering node in oracle?

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-update

I have list of elements inside xml like below

```
<Lists>
<Lists>
<list>
<Gender>Male</Gender>
<GenderCode>X</GenderCode>
</list>
<list>
<Gender>Female</Gender>
<GenderCode>X</GenderCode>
</list>
</Lists>
```

Here I need to update GenderCode value based on Gender's value. Suppose if Gender has 'Male' then I need to update GenderCode as 'M'. For 'Female' it should be 'F'. Is there a way to do filter Male list alone and update all GenderCodes of male List to 'M' and then filter Female alone and update GenderCode to 'F'. Can someone give suggestions in oracle PL/SQL or Java?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an XQuery update and set the code to the first character of the full value (assuming this isn't an overly-contrived example); using a static string:

```
select xmlquery (
  'copy $n := $o
   modify (
     for $g in $n/Lists/list
     return replace value of node $g/GenderCode with fn:substring($g/Gender, 1, 1)
   )
   return $n'
  passing xmltype('<Lists>
<list>
<Gender>Male</Gender>
<GenderCode>X</GenderCode>
</list>
<list>
<Gender>Female</Gender>
<GenderCode>X</GenderCode>
</list>
</Lists>') as "o"
  returning content)
from dual;

XMLQUERY('COPY$N:=$OMODIFY(FOR$GIN$N/LISTS/LISTRETURNREPLACEVALUEOFNODE$G/GENDER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Lists><list><Gender>Male</Gender><GenderCode>M</GenderCode></list><list><Gender
>Female</Gender><GenderCode>F</GenderCode></list></Lists>
```

Or probably more usefully, updating a value stored in a table as an XMLType:

```
-- create and populate dummy table
create table your_table (xml_column) as
select xmltype('<Lists>
<list>
<Gender>Male</Gender>
<GenderCode>X</GenderCode>
</list>
<list>
<Gender>Female</Gender>
<GenderCode>X</GenderCode>
</list>
</Lists>')
from dual;

update your_table
set xml_column = xmlquery (
  'copy $n := $o
   modify (
     for $g in $n/Lists/list
     return replace value of node $g/GenderCode with fn:substring($g/Gender, 1, 1)
   )
   return $n'
  passing xml_column as "o"
  returning content
);

1 row updated.
```

If your equivalent of `xml_column` is actually stored as a varchar2 or CLOB then just wrap it:

```
  passing xmltype(xml_column) as "o"
```

Then you can see that the value has been updated the way you wanted:

```
select xml_column from your_table;

XML_COLUMN                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Lists>
  <list>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <GenderCode>M</GenderCode>
  </list>
  <list>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <GenderCode>F</GenderCode>
  </list>
</Lists>
```

---

If the code needs to be looked up from a different table than you can use [`fn:collection` with `oradb`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-7B039748-7C2A-4D86-9C54-55F4D08ED59B) to access the table from within the XMLQuery:

```
-- undo previous update to go back to X codes
rollback;

-- look-up table
create table genders (gender, gendercode) as
select 'Male', 'M' from dual
union all
select 'Female', 'F' from dual;

update your_table
set xml_column = xmlquery (
  'copy $n := $o
   modify (
     for $g in $n/Lists/list, $c in fn:collection("oradb:/YOUR_SCHEMA/GENDERS")
       where $c/ROW/GENDER = $g/Gender
       return replace value of node $g/GenderCode with $c/ROW/GENDERCODE
   )
   return $n'
  passing xml_column as "o"
  returning content
);

1 row updated.
```

which gets the same result:

```
select xml_column from your_table;

XML_COLUMN                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Lists>
  <list>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <GenderCode>M</GenderCode>
  </list>
  <list>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <GenderCode>F</GenderCode>
  </list>
</Lists>
```

Comment: How I can handle in case of updating Area Code based on Area name? I have area and area code mapping in some other table. I need to do update like "case when area = Area1 then area_code = Area_Code1".
  <list>
    <Area>Area1</Gender>
    <AreaCode>X</AreaCode>
  </list>
  <list>
    <Area>Area2</Area>
    <AreaCode>X</AreaCode>
  </list>
</Lists>

Comment: @gunaseelanthirumal - code in comments doesn't really work, and unclear why you have now (partially) switched from genders to area codes. I've added a way to look up data from another table from within an XMLQuery call. In future please explain what you are really doing in your question, and include all relevant information, such as the contents of the look-up table and representative data and expected results. Your question seems to be significantly different from what you are actually trying to do. If this edit doesn't do what you need then please ask a new question, with all needed info.